# Toggle d3 shapes depending on button click

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I have a polygon and rectangle svg created and I also created a toggle button for a polygon and a rectangle as shown below and jfiddle as well.

What I am trying to achieve is initially both the rectangle and polygon should be displayed on the webpage, then if I click on "toggle polygon" the polygon should be shown and the rectangle should be hidden, and if I click on "toggle rect" the rectangle should be shown and polygon should be hidden.

I wrote the code below to achieve that but for some reason,both rectangle and polygon arent displayed first together and also the toggle buttons aren't even displaying proper shape even though I provided different function names to both.

```
              <!DOCTYPE html>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
                  <body>
                    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
                     <button onclick="myfunc" >Toggle polygon</button>
                     <button onclick="func">toggle rect</button>
                </body>
```

...

...

```
      var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", 1000)
     .attr("height", 667),

     scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-30,30])
    .range([0,600]),

    scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0,50])
    .range([500,0]),

   poly = [{"x":0.0, "y":25.0},
    {"x":8.5,"y":23.4},
    {"x":13.0,"y":21.0},
    {"x":19.0,"y":15.5}];
    
   var path;
    
   d3.select('button').on('click', function myfunc() {


if ( path ) {
    path.remove();
    // Remove dots
    path = null;
} else {

 path=vis.select("polygon")
.data([poly])
.enter().append("polygon")
.attr("points",function(d) { 
    return d.map(function(d) { return [scaleX(d.x),scaleY(d.y)].join(","); }).join(" ");})
.attr("stroke","black")
.attr("stroke-width",2);

}

});



var rect;

d3.select('button').on('click', function func() {


if ( rect ) {
    rect.remove();
    // Remove dots
    rect= null;
} else {

rect = vis
.append("rect")
.attr("x", 165)
.attr("y", 25)
.attr("height", 100)
.attr("width", 100)
.attr("fill", "#420a91")
.attr("stroke", "#FF00FF")
.attr("stroke-width", "4")
.attr("stroke-dasharray", "10,10");

}

});
```

...

http://jsfiddle.net/e2juf7op/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do...

```
d3.select('button').on('click',
```

... you are selecting *the first button* and setting a different listener to that same button (the last one overrides the first one).

The solution is either dropping the `selection.on` and relying on the inline `onclick` event or, alternatively, give those buttons different IDs. Also, remember that `selection.data()` follows `selectAll`.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 667),

  scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([-30, 30])
  .range([0, 600]),

  scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 50])
  .range([500, 0]),

  poly = [{
      "x": 0.0,
      "y": 25.0
    },
    {
      "x": 8.5,
      "y": 23.4
    },
    {
      "x": 13.0,
      "y": 21.0
    },
    {
      "x": 19.0,
      "y": 15.5
    }
  ];

var path;

d3.select('#btn1').on('click', function myfunc() {


  if (path) {
    path.remove();
    // Remove dots
    path = null;
  } else {

    path = vis.selectAll("polygon")
      .data([poly])
      .enter().append("polygon")
      .attr("points", function(d) {
        return d.map(function(d) {
          return [scaleX(d.x), scaleY(d.y)].join(",");
        }).join(" ");
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2);

  }

});



var rect;

d3.select('#btn2').on('click', function func() {


  if (rect) {
    rect.remove();
    // Remove dots
    rect = null;
  } else {

    rect = vis
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", 165)
      .attr("y", 25)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("fill", "#420a91")
      .attr("stroke", "#FF00FF")
      .attr("stroke-width", "4")
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", "10,10");

  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <button id="btn1">Toggle polygon</button>
  <button id="btn2">toggle rect</button>
</body>
```